# Aligning textviews

Tags: android, layout

I am developing an android app whose relative layout is given below.

Here is an imgur link to how the app shows on screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oaLz.jpg. I would like 'Text 1' to appear right above 'a lazy fox ..'. Hope that helps clarify what I wish to accomplish.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"


        android:textColor="@color/black" android:text="Text 1" android:lines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:ellipsize="end" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/checkBox" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:drawableRight="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked_30"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1" android:background="@color/white" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox" android:layout_below="@+id/text1"


        android:textColor="@color/black" android:text="a lazy fox jumped over the dam and said help"

        android:lines="1" android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:ellipsize="end" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text2" android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Text 3" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text4" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text3" android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Text 4" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text5" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text4" android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Text 5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want "Text 1" to appear right above the text that starts off with "a lazy fox...". Right now 'Text 1' appears above the checkbox. I am not sure how to achieve the above. I have tried various things but nothing seems to be working. What should I be doing to achieve the desired layout?

Comment: Please provide an image of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Macarse I cannot as rep is too low.

Comment: Post is somewhere else and provide us with the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was targeting Android 1.5 in which forward references do not work in RelativeLayout. Forward references were first implemented in Android 1.6 (See: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/ui-1.6.html) and hence any of the suggested solutions by others were not working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `layout_alightLeft` attribute to your `text1`:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" 
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text2"
    ...
/>
```

[image]

---

Full layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text2"
        android:text="Text 1"
        android:lines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
        android:ellipsize="end" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkBox" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:text="button"  />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"         
        android:text="a lazy fox jumped over the dam and said help"
        android:lines="1" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
         android:ellipsize="end" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text3" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text2"        
        android:text="Text 3" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text4" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text3"        
        android:text="Text 4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text4"        
        android:text="Text 5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with full copy of my layout file. Try it.

Comment: that is interesting. it does not work. Is this by any chance api specific? I am targeting sdk version 3 (android 1.5).

Comment: I've just tried that with target SDK set to 3, and it also works.

Comment: ok then the problem lies elsewhere because I did not change your layout file at all before running it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can do next: create new project, paste this layout, start and test it on emulator. See if you can reproduce this.

Comment: I tried with a new project but no luck. I even tried using a phone instead of the emulator but it does not work.

Comment: I've updated the layout, can you please copy it form this post one more time and try it in your new project?

Comment: nope. it does not work. I tried lots of different things including the layout_alignLeft attribute but for some reason it does not work on either the emulator or on the phone.

Comment: ok, I figured this out. Android 1.5 cannot handle forward references whereas Android 1.6 does. See: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/ui-1.6.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want the "Text1" to show up right above/aligned with "a lazy fox...".

Try changing the definition of the first TextView to this (notice the last attribute):

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="Text 1"
    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text2" />
```

EDIT:
Here's the full layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Text 1"
    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked_30"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"


    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="a lazy fox jumped over the dam and said help"

    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Text 3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text3"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Text 4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text4"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Text 5" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the full layout so I can run at my end and compare with what I have?

Comment: Check the edit. I'm really curious now, why this isn't working for you. In your code are you accessing & doing anything with the widgets? Or are you just loading this file?

Comment: The code simply loads the xml file. There is no other processing that is being done. Your layout does not work. I have no idea why!

Comment: ok, I figured this out. Android 1.5 cannot handle forward references whereas Android 1.6 does. See: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/ui-1.6.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `android: layout_below="@id/editText2"` to `text1`